# Mongoose Error: Cannot use a writeConcern without a provided callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am am using the Mongoose 3.8.23, Express 4.0.0,

When updating the record with upsert option. I am getting the error.

```
var queryId = {_id: aggDate + '/' + event + '/' + platform};
var dailySet = {$set: {}};
    dailySet.$set['day'] = 0;
    dailySet.$set['metadata.event'] = event;
    dailySet.$set['metadata.platform'] = platform;
    dailySet.$set['metadata.date'] = today;
aggregateModel.update(queryId, dailySet, {upsert: true}, function (err, numUpdated) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(err, null);
    } else {
        console.log(numUpdated);
        callback(null, numUpdated);
    }
});
```

**For reference:**

First, I am working on the pre-aggregate use case for pre-allocation. For the first time, the collection couldn't be created. If I run on mongoshell, it's working but not from the script.

Schema:

```
_id: String, 
metadata: { date: String, platform: String, event: String },
day: Schema.Types.Mixed, 
hour: Schema.Types.Mixed, 
minute: Schema.Types.Mixed
```

Error:

> Error: Cannot use a writeConcern without a provided callback at Collection.updatevar/www/html/mapm/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/li‌​b/mongodb/collection/core.js:719:11) at NativeCollection.(anonymous function) [as update] (/var/www/html/mapm/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collec‌​tion.js:135:28) at NodeCollection.update (/var/www/html/mapm/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mquery/lib/collection/nod‌​e.js:61:19)

Comment: Hi, are you can show me you Model and error, pls.

Comment: `_id: String,
    metadata: {
        date: String,        
        platform: String,
        event: String
    },
    day: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    hour: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    minute: Schema.Types.Mixed
}`

Comment: Error is:  Error: Cannot use a writeConcern without a provided callback
    at Collection.updatevar/www/html/mapm/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js:719:11)
    at NativeCollection.(anonymous function) [as update] (/var/www/html/mapm/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:135:28) at NodeCollection.update (/var/www/html/mapm/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mquery/lib/collection/node.js:61:19)

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what `queryId` and `dailySet` contain?

Comment: @JohnnyHK user3776269 Updated my question. Can any one give some hint. what's the issue is?

Comment: Your code looks fine and it worked when I tried it.